# Stack size on BlackBerry?

Tags: memory, blackberry, operating-system, stack

I know that on Symbian stack size is equal to 8k. What about BlackBerry?

Comment: Asked the same question on BlackBerry forums http://tinyurl.com/ne2hyz

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps [this thread on the BlackBerry Forums](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/board/message?board.id=java_dev&view=by_date_ascending&message.id=46034#M46034) is helpful:

> I don't believe there is any way to [ increase stack size for threads ]
>   in the BB environment. Stack Size
>   is initialized by the JVM, and we have
>   no access to JVM parameters in the BB
>   OS, AFAIK.